# CsvHelper - Custom parser for a certain column

Tags: csvhelper

Is therer a good way to override the parsing for a certain column/field i.e. for not well-formatted documents containing a json object. Stream reading json & therby moving stream forward past the incorrect/malformatted csv field but also saving/returning json.

Preferable in combination CsvDataReader & DataTable.Load

Edit - clarify sample:
col_a;col_b;col_c;col_json
0.0;-1;0;{"t": 1598270895, "text": "hello world" }

Comment: Is the JSON field properly escaped? Meaning, it contains `"`s around it and any `"` inside is doubled like `""`?

Comment: Do you have some example data?

Comment: No not escaped - but would be parsable with json read:
Conceptually:
0.0;-1;0;{"t": 1598270895, "text": "hello world" }
But text can be worse with line breaks or semicolon in it - a more complex json but that is irrelevant.

Is it possible to override one field

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is supposed to work, but I did find that just setting `BadDataFound = null` worked with the latest version of CsvHelper and your example data.

It doesn't, however, work if "text" has line breaks or semicolon in it.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        BadDataFound = null,
        Delimiter = ";"
    };
    using(var reader = new StringReader("col_a;col_b;col_c;col_json\n0.0;-1;0;{\"t\": 1598270895, \"text\": \"hello world\"}"))
    using(var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dt.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice & interesting - but would be better if one can override like a column "reader" and stream read in some way that position is synchronized / moved forward.

Comment: I don't see any way to do that with CsvHelper.  Even if you manually use `Read()` to bring in each line, if the json isn't properly escaped, CsvHelper won't correctly read the whole line if the json has a semicolon or line break in it.  The only way I could see it working is if you could somehow throw in a json parser for that column.

Comment: was hoping there was a way to hook one in if lucky....override reading of column stream-reading & make sure the all pointer/stream positions are aligned.